# why await doesn't suspend the parent function

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

According to https://realpython.com/async-io-python/,

> The keyword await passes function control back to the event loop. (It suspends the execution of the surrounding coroutine.) If Python encounters an await f() expression in the scope of g(), this is how await tells the event loop, “Suspend execution of g() until whatever I’m waiting on—the result of f()—is returned. In the meantime, go let something else run.”

```
import asyncio
import time

async def spend_time(name):
    print(f"spending time for {name}")
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(f"{name} sleep {i}")


async def first():
    print("first task...")
    await spend_time("first")
    print("first task finished")

async def second():
    print("second task...")
    await spend_time("second")
    print("second task finished")
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(first(), second()))
```

For code above, I expect that after printing "first task", it will give control to another coroutines and print "second task", because it await, but it's not.

```
first task...
spending time for first
first sleep 0
first sleep 1
first sleep 2
first sleep 3
first sleep 4
first task finished
second task...
spending time for second
second sleep 0
second sleep 1
second sleep 2
second sleep 3
second sleep 4
second task finished
```

Why doesn't it suspend the execution of first task?

Answer (score 0):

`time.sleep` is a blocking call (it doesn't return the control back to the event loop), you should use `asyncio.sleep` instead:

```py
import asyncio

async def spend_time(name):
    print(f"spending time for {name}")
    for i in range(5):
        await asyncio.sleep(1) # awaiting, returning the control
        print(f"{name} sleep {i}")


async def first():
    print("first task...")
    await spend_time("first")
    print("first task finished")


async def second():
    print("second task...")
    await spend_time("second")
    print("second task finished")


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(first(), second()))
loop.close()
```

Output:

```
first task...
spending time for first
second task...
spending time for second
first sleep 0
second sleep 0
first sleep 1
second sleep 1
first sleep 2
second sleep 2
first sleep 3
second sleep 3
first sleep 4
first task finished 
second sleep 4      
second task finished
```

Comment: The question is I didn't even expect "spending time for first" to be printed after "first task", since the control is already given to the other coroutines at await according to the document

Comment: @BobLee Good observation. The document is slightly imprecise - `await` doesn't automatically pass control to the event loop. It _can_ pass control to the event loop and does so as soon as the awaitee (or its own awaitee if it uses `await`, and so on) chooses to suspend.

Comment: @user4815162342, what is the action for awaitee to do a suspend, I mean I know almost all the examples use asyncio.sleep to do this task, but I don't see the value of doing this in real scenario. The real scenario is something like, read a file, request a url, etc, and I know there are some libs such as aiohttp that does the suspend, but what is the actual final action to do the suspend in the long await calling chain besides asyncio.sleep? If I simply read a file in the async function, it will just block it until it's completed instead of suspend it.

Comment: @BobLee In asyncio a simple low-level (but still public) way to effect a suspend is by creating a future with `loop.create_future()` and awaiting it. The coroutine that does so will immediately and unconditionally suspend to the event loop (along with its awaiters), and will resume when someone completes the future by calling `set_result()` or `set_exception()`. Correctly written code will take steps to ensure that this eventually happens before awaiting the future. For example, `sleep(delay)` could be implemented as `f = create_future(); loop.call_later(delay, f.set_result, None); await f`.

Comment: @BobLee For further details about how await is implemented and what it "does" at the language level, see [this lecture](https://youtu.be/7JtNiwCH_OA). For more details about how an event loop is implemented, see [this demonstration](https://youtu.be/MCs5OvhV9S4), where the lecturer implements a simple but functional event loop in front of live audience.

Comment: @user4815162342, for your comment "Correctly written code will take steps to ensure that this eventually happens before awaiting the future", the problem is I didn't find another way except loop.call_later to achieve this, and loop.call_later is just another asynio.sleep for me. For example, after create_future, I want the set_result be called after a file is read successfully.I only know that loop.run_in_executor could run the blocking code in a thread and return a future,but this just doesn't feel like what asyncio should do as it involves threading,there must be a native way to achieve this

Comment: @BobLee It's hard to recommend a solution without understanding what problem you are attempting to solve. Your question only contains a toy example which is incorrect because it blocks inside a coroutine (using `time.sleep`, which you've been correctly told to replace with `asyncio.sleep`). If you have blocking code, `run_in_executor` is probably precisely what you need - the "future" it returns is something you just await, and let other things run. That **is** the native way to execute CPU-bound code.